# Installing ggplot in python 3.6.3

Tags: python, ggplot2, pip, conda

I am transitioning from R and would like to use ggplot in the yhat Rodeo IDE.

I have tried installing ggplot for python 3.6.3 (Anaconda 5.0.1 64-bit) in a number of ways.

When trying to install any kind of ggplot via conda i get this:
"UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
-ggplot
-zict" 
I am aware that ggplot does not work with the most recent version of python, so i tried installing an older version and received the same error.

I then thought to try pip, and ensured that pip was installed and up to date via conda.

In rodeo when i try to use "! pip install ggplot" i get the "pip.exe has stopped working" error. Same for easy_install, etc.

Any ideas? It seems that i can't install it in any way.

Comment: You can check the Seaborn package. It has a similar functionality to ggplot.

Answer (score 1):

Try making a fresh conda environment and only request the installation of `ggplot`:

`conda create --name my_new_env -c conda-forge ggplot`

This installed ggplot v0.11.5 and python v3.6.3 for me just now (Ubuntu 17.10)